# Why is same Json content omitted in rest service output?

Tags: java, json, spring-data-rest, spring-data-neo4j

The usual controller, model and repository are below:

Model:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
@NodeEntity
public class Movie {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    private int released;

    private String tagline;

    @Relationship(type = "ACTED_IN", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
     ...
}
```

Controller:

```
    @RestController("/")
public class MovieController {

    final MovieService movieService;

    @Autowired
    public MovieController(MovieService movieService) {
        this.movieService = movieService;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/query")
    public Map<String, Object> query(@RequestParam(value = "limit",required = false) Integer limit) {
        return movieService.query(limit == null ? 1 : limit);
    }
}
```

Service:

```
    @Service
public class MovieService {

    @Autowired MovieRepository movieRepository;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Map<String, Object>  query(int limit) {
        Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>(2);
        Collection<Movie> r1 = movieRepository.query(2);
        Collection<Movie> r2 = movieRepository.query(2);
        result.put("firstQuery", r1);
        result.put("secondSameQuery", r2);
        return result;

    }
}
```

Repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "movies", path = "movies")
public interface MovieRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Movie, Long> {

    @Query("MATCH (m:Movie)<-[r:ACTED_IN]-(a:Person) RETURN m, r, a LIMIT {limit}")
    Collection<Movie> query(@Param("limit") int limit);
}
```

In the service class, I am testing to combine two query results into one with the same query, so the results from two queries are the same. When I put them into the Map, I suppose two different keys with the same content. However, in the HTTP rest service, I can see from my browser that the result from the second query are almost omitted, because they are the same? For "secondQuery", it only prints out the id "60". Why is that? is there a way not to let it omit in the json output?

```
{
  "firstQuery": [
    {
      "id": 60,
      "title": "The Matrix",
      "released": 1999,
      "tagline": "Welcome to the Real World",
      "roles": [
        {
          "id": 60,
          "roles": [
            "Neo"
          ],
          "person": {
            "id": 61,
            "name": "Keanu Reeves",
            "born": 1964,
            "movies": [

            ]
          },
          "movie": 60
        },
        {
          "id": 67,
          "roles": [
            "Emil"
          ],
          "person": {
            "id": 68,
            "name": "Emil Eifrem",
            "born": 1978,
            "movies": [

            ]
          },
          "movie": 60
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "secondSameQuery": [
    60
  ]
}
```

Comment: it seems it automatically merged content (r1 and r2) into one JSON object, so the second put : result.put("secondSameQuery", r2) doesn't achieve the effect. I want two query results to stay separately so that I can put them into the map with different keys. How to avoid the automatic merging behind the scene?

Answer (score 0):

This is common behaviour of the jackson library when using the `@JsonIdentityInfo` annotation. If you read the [JavaDoc](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIdentityInfo.html) you find the phrase:

> ... In practice this is done by serializing the **first instance as full object** and object identity, and **other references to the object as reference values**.